# What cable do I need to connect rows of male header pins together

Tags: connector, cables

I have a [Jaguar](http://www.luminarymicro.com/jaguar) motor controller that has a set of 5 inset male header pins to connect an encoder. The encoder has only loose wires coming out.

What type of connector should I be buying to solder/crimp onto the end of these?

Also, there're a couple of sensor boards with a similar arrangement of 0.1" male headers. The control board also has male headers. However, every compatible cable I can find is male to female.

Do servo cables with sockets at both ends exist?

---

This is what the controller looks like. Encoder slot is on the front, as the freehand-circling below shows

[image: Jaguar]

Comment: Any chance you could post a pic of the header pins to make sure we point you in the right direction?

Comment: @RQDQ: Added pic of jaguar

Comment: Picture updated to show where cables go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are those jumpers beside the connector? Then probably the connector can be connected using the common [jumper wires](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9140) (available with up to at least 10 pins in one housing).
Servo cables usually have a different kind of connector (rounded corners).

To make your own jumper leads, you can buy [crimp connector housings](http://pololu.com/catalog/product/1904) from [pololu](http://pololu.com/). They also sell [pre-crimped wires](http://pololu.com/catalog/category/71), if you don't want to crimp them yourself.

Comment: Yes, those are jumpers. What I want to know how to do is turn attach the 5 loose wires that come out of the encoder onto a set of jumper cable ends, preferably without cannibalizing jumper cables.

Comment: I'm having difficulty finding multi-wire jumper cables that aren't polarized. Can you point me to some? Or is it not the done thing to use one large connector at each end?

Comment: If you don't want to crimp them yourself (tool needed), you can get http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/1904 and put http://www.pololu.com/catalog/category/71 inside them.

Comment: Damn. I just ordered a bunch from [farnell](http://uk.farnell.com/). I would have much preferred to buy them from polulu. Thanks anyway. Those are exactly what I was looking for.